# Why does GDB shows the status exited normally when the array index is out of bounds?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb

```
void main()
{
        int arr[3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
                printf("arr is %d\n", arr[i]);
        }
}
```

Here is the output from GDB:

```
Starting program: /home/mayank/practice/test1 
arr is 1
arr is 2
arr is 3
arr is -1192452352
arr is 1079472019
arr is 1431652464

[Inferior 1 (process 29328) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Undefined behavior comes with no guarantee whatsoever, not even a crash, error message or a certain exit status.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text as text instead. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This code comes with a ton of warnings. Instead of ignoring them, read them. And in the future always compile with `-pedantic-errors` so that you get compiler errors when you write invalid C.

Comment: I have written this code to intentionally produce warnings because GDB was showing the program has 'exited normally'.

Comment: The code isn't valid C. If gcc still somehow produced an executable, what it does is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you access an array out-of-bounds you get undefined behavior. And undefined behavior is just that: *undefined*. Nothing might happen, or your program might crash, all depending or not if the moon is in the seventh house, or the famous [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) might bother you.

In your test program you just *read* behind the allocated array, additionally. With some knowledge of the actual compiler and target system you might explain what really happens. In many cases, like yours, nothing bad happens beside the strange values printed. And so, the application exits happily.

As long as you don't instruct GDB to watch your application on accesses outside the array, GDB will not notice that.

*Note: Some compilers have an option to instrument the generated code to check array indexes.*